# How would you approach the limit $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \sin ||z||_p}{||z||_p}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

How would I solve the limit

$\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \sin ||z||_p}{||z||_p}$ ?

Note that $p \in [1,\infty]$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts 
on it are and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts; this will prevent people 
from telling you thngs you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level

Comment: What space does $z$ "live in"? And why is it even necessary to go through that -- why do you even need the $p$-norm there? This is absolutely the same as $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$, for $x > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose $z=(z_1,\dots,z_n)\in\Bbb R^n$, so that $||z||_p=(z_1^p+\cdots+z_n^p)^{1/p}$. So let's set $f(z):=(z_1^p+\cdots+z_n^p)^{1/p}$; $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$.

Clearly $f(z)\to 0$ as $z\to0$. So your limit is
$$
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin||z||_p}{||z||_p}=
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin f(z)}{f(z)}\stackrel{f(z)=w}{=}
\lim_{w\to0}\frac{\sin w}w=1
$$

for the well known limit already recalled above.